# Continuous extension theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $g$ be a continuous function on the interval $(a,b)$. Prove that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ iff it is possible to define $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ so that the extended function is continuous on $[a,b]$.

I want to know if my forward direction is correct. Set $g(a) = \inf( g((a,b))$. $\inf( g((a,b)) < \infty$ as uniform functions map bounded sets to bounded sets. Suppose that $x_i \longrightarrow a$ we want to show that $f(x_i) \longrightarrow f(a)$.  Since $f(a)$ is infimum so for every $\epsilon > 0: f(a) + \epsilon$ is no longer an infimum.

Thus, there exists $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_i) \in V_{\epsilon}(f(a))$. Suppose that $f(x_i)$ doesn't converge to $f(a)$. Then there exists $\epsilon_{0}$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $|f(x_i) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon_0$ for $n \geq N$. Setting $N = i$ we arrive at a contradiction.

Therefore $f(x_i) \longrightarrow f(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach does not work in general. For instance, if $(a,b)=(-1,1)$ and $g(x)=x^2$, then setting $g(-1)=\inf\{g(x):x\in(-1,1)\}=0$ does not yield the correct value for $g(-1)$.

Instead, choose a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $(a,b)$ converging to $a$. Since uniformly continuous functions map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, the sequence $\{g(x_n)\}$ will have a limit. You can then check that setting $g(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)$ makes $g$ continuous at $a$.

Comment: Yeah I also thought about this. Thank you !